# Как возвратить тип int из класса в C++

Tags: c++, ооп, классы

При попытке вернуть интовое значение из класса выдает рандомное число:

```
class tess {
    private:
    int a;

    public:
    void set(int a){
        a = a;
    }
    int get()
    {
        return a;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вернуть - так вы возвращаете...

Но вот устанавливать его кто будет? Страуструп? :)

Здесь

```
void set(int a){
    a = a;
}
```

вы просто присваиваете переданный аргумент самому себе...

```
void set(int a){
    this->a = a;
}
```

или

```
void set(int b){
    a = b;
}
```